# Hibernate quiz modeling

Tags: java, hibernate, modeling

Currently, I'm dealing with a modeling problem. The subject is simple and still, I haven't found any solution.

A player, with first and last name, answers for multiple questions. The questions and answers are in text format and **the order is important**.

Example:

Player John Doe has answered 3 questions:

```
1: "What is your favorite city?" -> "London"
2: "What is your favorite color?" -> "Red"
3: "What is your favorite sport?" -> "Football"
```

So in my Hibernate bean of "Player", I need to be able to access directly to the player's questions/answers. I need also update the questions/answers or remove some.

First of all, what is the best way to present this in a database (one or two tables) and secondly, how do I map it?

Thank you

**Edit:** here is what I tried so far:

On database side, I've 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "player" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "first_name" text NOT NULL,
    "last_name" text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "player_quest_answers" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "player_id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "idx" int4 DEFAULT NULL, //For order
    "question" text NOT NULL,
    "answer" text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "player_data_pkey" PRIMARY KEY("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "fk_player_data" FOREIGN KEY "player_id" REFERENCES player("id")
);
```

In hibernate, I have no idea how to modelise what I need.

**Edit 2:** After following Tuğrul Altun link for the tutorial, I now have 2 tables "player" and "player_quest_answers", like in the first edit.

My hibernate mapping looks like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="mypackage">
    <class name="Player" table="player">

        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="text" />
        <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="text" />

        <list name="questAnswers" table="user_data" cascade="all">
            <key column="player_id" />
            <list-index column="idx" />
            <one-to-many class="PlayerQuestAnswers" />
        </list>
    </class>

    <class name="PlayerQuestAnswers" table="player_quest_answers">

        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="question" column="question" type="text" />
        <property name="answer" column="answer" type="text" />
    </class>    
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But when I'm trying to execute the following scenario it doesn't work:

```
    mySession.beginTransaction();

    PlayerQuestAnswer firstQA = new PlayerQuestAnswer();
    firstQA.setQuestion("Question 1");
    firstQA.setAnswer("Answer 1");

    PlayerQuestAnswer secondQA = new PlayerQuestAnswer();
    secondQA.setQuestion("Question 2");
    secondQA.setAnswer("Answer 2");

    List<PlayerQuestAnswer> qaList = new ArrayList<PlayerQuestAnswer>();
    qaList.add(firstQA);
    qaList.add(secondQA);

    Player myPlayer = new Player();
    myPlayer.setFirstName("John");
    myPlayer.setLastName("Doe");
    myPlayer.setQuestAnswers(qaList);

    mySession.save(myPlayer);
    mySession.getTransaction().commit();
```

at this point, everything goes well, I've this in my DB:

```
player
--------------------------------
id  | first_name | last_name
--------------------------------
1   |     John   |   Doe

player_quest_answers
---------------------------------------------------
id  | player_id |   question   |   answer   | idx
---------------------------------------------------
1   |     1     | "Question 1" | "Answer 1" |  0
2   |     1     | "Question 2" | "Answer 2" |  1
```

And when I do this:

```
mySession.beginTransaction();
player.getQuestAnswers().remove(1);
mySession.saveOrUpdate(myPlayer);
mySession.getTransaction().commit();
```

it throws me 2 steps HibernateException:

```
 batch 0 "update PlayerQuestData set player=null where id=2" was cancelled
 the query violates the NOT NULL constraint on player_id
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Post what you've tried so far.

Comment: If 1 question can be for more roles -> 2 tables (`questions` and `question_role`). In the second one can be column `order` for setting a position on question.

Comment: @Dave I added what I tried

Comment: @panther What is the "role" you're talking about? I can't see it my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these modeling types:

- Many-to-One
- One-to-One
- One-to-Many
- Many-to-Many

Comment: Ok if I choose to use "One-to-Many", what and how it must be done in Hibernate mapping?

Comment: you can find more detail in here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_or_mappings.htm

Comment: Ok, I tried this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_one_to_many_mapping.htm It works but I ve a weird error. I edited my original topic about that, could you check it (edit 2), please. Thank you